# django ORM performance when using paginator with normal lists

Tags: django, orm

Long story short, I am using polymorphic models and some queries I just cannot do as normal, so I have to convert the query result into a normal list. Then use the paginator to page results.

To put things into perspective, normally we would do it like this:

```
instances = Model.objects.filter(field=True)
Paginator(instances, 10).page(1)
```

In my case:

```
instances = [x for x in Model.objects.filter(field=True)]
Paginator(instances, 10).page(1)
```

Given the ORM is lazy, so normally when paged, the raw query will have OFFSET and LIMITS which makes the query very lightweight. But in my case, since I am looping through the query result, I am actually hitting the database for all instances, then apply pagination.

I tried to read the raw queries by printing `connection.queries` but the polymorphic model queries are kind of headache to read through.

So hopefully this will be a quick question for anyone knows the guts of django ORM.

**EDIT**

To anyone who is curious why I need to convert to a list, have a look at this link and look for my problem https://github.com/bconstantin/django_polymorphic/issues/19 my way to work around it is to loop through the tags and filter in the loop as below:

```
_items = []
for tag in tags:
  for item in items.filter(tags__slug = tag):
    # get unique items
    if item not in _items:
      _items.append(item)

# sadly the following doesn't work due to polymorphic query limitation
# _items = None
# for item in items.filter(tags__slug = tag):
#   _items = _items | items.filter(tags__slug = tag)
```

Comment: Paginator will still work. But i am curious to know what force you to force the queryset to list?

Comment: @AamirAdnan the reason of why is here https://github.com/bconstantin/django_polymorphic/issues/19